# TextBox not showing in WinForms form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I am adding a TextBox to my form at runtime, and this is a brand new project, so this is the only code I have so far, so I am 100% positive that this is not my own doing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox box = new TextBox();
            box.Location = new Point(2, 2);

            this.Controls.Add(box);
        }
    }
}
```

Why won't the TextBox display? There's nothing at all. I set breakpoints all over the place, but none of them how anything that could help me. All *seems* normal, but isn't.

Comment: @HansPassant, there is nothing wrong with the code here. I added the button using the designer - the designer takes care of the rest. The button1_Click **does** run because when this code did not work I replaced it with a MessageBox.Show() - and guess what - the MessageBox displayed when I clicked the button. Why would you assume that I'm not "properly subscribing to an event handler"? It's obvious that I am - and there's no reason to assume otherwise. I've been doing this for years - the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @user2645707 does your form has any other control? I guess your form has some `Panel` with `Dock=DockStyle.Fill` and hence you can't see the added `TextBox`.

Comment: If you have that button in place, your code works perfectly. I just replicated it and got a small textbox at the top left corner when I clicked the button.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code exactly as you have it in a new solution (after I dragged a button on to the form and double clicked on it in the IDE to make sure the event was attached to the button) and worked exactly as it should.  A text box is placed on the form @ 2,2.  If you have an issue somewhere, it's not in the code that you posted.

Comment: Yes, that is the only thing I have on my form - just the button. And yes, that's what I'm trying to get at - I don't know _what_ the problem is - and I'm showing you the code because someone would have eventually asked for it - and also to show that there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: The code you posted is a partial class. The other parts that define this class (that you haven't posted here) may contain the issue.

Comment: Place a breakpoint on your Controls.Add(box) line and see what the Size of your Textbox is.

Comment: I've already set breakpoints everywhere, @MarkHall but thanks. Like I said in the question - everything _seems_ normal. The Size is the default size that gets set by the designer, I've even tried changing it to multiline and Width=300/Height=300 - I've even tried adding a few other different controls and they all display - just not the textbox.

Comment: @user2645707 you've tried adding a few other different controls in the `button1_Click` event handler?

Comment: Correct. Only one at a time though. I've added a Panel, and RichTextBox and LinkLabel and FlowLayoutPanel but TextBox is the only one that doesn't show up. I've even (just now) tried rebuilding the project but the TB still won't show. I also just created a new black project and added a button to the form and the TB still won't show.

Comment: What's with all the downvotes? It's a legitimate question and as far as I know - I haven't done anything wrong here. I've already tried everything I could think of and everything that's been suggested.

Comment: As others have stated your code works on my computer, Take a good look at your `InitializeComponent` Method to make sure something isn't amiss there.

Comment: @user2645707 it's very strange, there must something wrong with your `TextBox`, try setting its `Visible = true`? (although true is default value).

Comment: It looks like winforms has serious "TextBox Rendering Issues"... You'd rather stick to WPF.. it's  much more reliable in so many ways.

Comment: @HighCore that's the OP problem (not `winforms`), I'm sure that if it was mine, I would solve it quickly. in fact I've never encountered such a strange thing. Since the day I've learned `WPF`, I really understand why you hate `winforms`, however I still love both, but for sure I'll go for `WPF` in any new project of mine :)

Comment: I know you've mentioned you've checked the size and set the `Width` and `Height` properties but [this example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319266) shows setting `Location` *and* `Size` before adding it.

Comment: @KingKing nevermind, that's an internal joke between me and the OP because of a previous discussion.

Comment: @HighCore. I actually found that funny. Lol. I feel so dumb right now.

Comment: Tried your code just now and works perfectly fine. No problem/s occured here on my side.

Answer (score 3):

The code is very simple, the only reason I can think of is you have some other control added before (wide enough to cover the added `TextBox`), try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox box = new TextBox();
        box.Location = new Point(2, 2);
        this.Controls.Add(box);
        box.BringToFront();
    }
```

Also check the event handler `ControlAdded`, I guess the form has some code for this event handler and discard the control added if it's type of `TextBox`, something like this:

```
private void form_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e) {
   if(e.Control is TextBox) Controls.Remove(e.Control);
}
```

Comment: thanks. I did already try BringToFront (even though the button (located at 50,50) is the only control on the form) but there's no point since it's not necessary - but it still didn't help.

Comment: @user2645707 try rebuilding or cleaning and building your solution again, there is something wrong with your current project.

Answer (score 1):

The code that adds the textbox to the form is in button1_Click event handler.  If you move it to the constructor, it will work just fine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TextBox box = new TextBox();
            box.Location = new Point(2, 2);

            this.Controls.Add(box);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Then you should mention that when you post the question. It's not my problem to try to anticipate what the hell you really asking.

On the other hand, make sure the button1_click is handled.  Try adding this line button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(button1_Click);

Comment: @user2645707    You're aware that this guy is taking his own time to try to help you?

Comment: @ChaiNavawongse I am sorry, that aggression wasn't meant for you. I was frustrated because some people have made so many assumptions and accusations and it just gets to me sometimes. It's hard to not get pissed off when it's always happening and they're wrong about it. Thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

Looking at the code I found out that the textboxes that DO show were of type System.Windows.Forms.TextBox while those that DID NOT show were of type VisualJS.Web.TextBox.  Perhaps your problem is similar.